# remove double square brackets and keep the string

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all square brackets from a string and keep the string. I've been looking around but all topic OP's want to replace the string with something.

So: [[link_to_page]]

should become: link_to_page

I think I should use php regex, can someone assist me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to extract link_to_page from a full text, or are you sure your string start with [[ and end with ]] (ie. contains only [[link_to_page]])?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use a str_replace.

```
$string = str_replace(array('[[',']]'),'',$string);
```

But this would get a '[[' without a ']]' closure. And a ']]' without a '[[' opening.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what you want - but...

If you simply want to "remove all square brackets" without worrying about pairing/etc then a simple str_replace will do it:

```
str_replace( array('[',']') , ''  , $string )
```

That is not (and doesn't need to be) a regex.

If you want to unwrap paired double brackets, with unknown contents, then a regex replace is what you want, which uses [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead.

Since `[` and `]` are metacharacters in regex, they need to be escaped with a backslash.

To match all instances of double-bracketed text, you can use the pattern `\[\[\w+\[\]` and to replace those brackets you can put the contents into a capture group (by surrounding with parentheses) and replace all instances like so:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/\[\[(\w+)\[\]/' , '$1' , $string );
```

The `\w` matches any alphanumeric or underscore - if you want to allow more/less characters it can be updated, e.g. `\[\[([a-z\-_]+)\[\]` or whatever makes sense.

If you want to act on the contents of the square brackets, see the [answer by fluminis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182087/remove-double-square-brackets-and-keep-the-string#19182557).

Comment: the str_replace with array('[',']') is an awesome example.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(\[|\]){2}/', '', '[[link_to_page]]');
```

OR using `str_replace`:

```
$repl = str_replace(array('[[', ']]'), '', '[[link_to_page]]');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one match :

```
preg_match('/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/', $yourText, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // will echo link_to_page
```

Or if you want to extract all the link from a text

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/', $yourText, $matches);
foreach($matches as $link) {
   echo $link[1];
}
```

How to read `'/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/'`

- `/` start the regex
- `\[\[` two `[` characters but need to escape them because [ is a meta caracter
- `([^\]]+)` get all chars that are not a ]
- `\]\]` two `]` characters but need to escape them because ] is a meta caracter
- `/` end the regex

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace(/(\[\[)|(\]\])/, '', $string);
```